# Is it possible to mix extjs and GWT components?

Tags: gwt, extjs

I am working with GWT2.3 version.I also found ExtJs4 framework very good and want to club the some of component of ExtJs4 in my application(GWT2.3).So I just want to know it is possible to club components of ExtJs4 with GWT application

Thanks in Adcance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is. Just add .js source to your public folder in /src. Then you can write custom JavaScript as native methods via JSNI. See more [in the docs](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsJSNI.html).

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the GWT compatible project? http://www.sencha.com/products/extgwt/

It has the same widget library (afaik) and integrates quite nicely w/ GWT